# Are there any stats about skill ratings in Dota 2?

Tags: dota-2

I just got told that if you search for recent games, your games are organized into skill brackets.

Since all my solo matches are in "very high" and I dont consider myself very skilled, and i do a lot of dicking around i wonder how big the "very high" skill bracket is, it must be pretty big.

Are there any Stats from Replay parser/ api sites how many players/matches are in what bracket?

Comment: Where are you searching for recent games? In-game or some website? Where do you see which skill bracket that your games fall into?

Comment: If you search ingame (Watch --> Recent Games) now you can search for you name and also filter for skill brackets(normal,high,very high). This way you can determine which matches are in which skill brackets. But i guess there is no real answer what these skill brackets mean.

Comment: Reportedly top 4% is Very High, next 20% is high, the rest is Normal.

Comment: So, 4% of what? 20% of what? What is it calculated from?

Answer (score 0):

The skill that appears next to replays is linked to the winrate on which dota 2 matchmaking is based, and perhaps profile level.

So if you are low/mid skilled  can get to play in high skilled rated games to balance the teams.

You can use this website to search for users and yourself, and check the available stats recorded: [DotaBuff](http://dotabuff.com/) .

Comment: Valve has stated that in no way is win rate used in the matchmaking process.. http://www.playdota.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1125953

Comment: Well at least they used to do it, but they dropped it recently.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but even so, 8 months later and it's still a very good one (in my opinion).

A fair bit has changed and now the game is out of beta and the ranked ladder system is in place. Each player has a solo and team MMR rating which is displayed on their profile.

It's now a lot more transparent in terms of how we are placed in matches.

This is the rough distribution according to valve prior to launching the ranked match making system. http://blog.dota2.com/2013/12/matchmaking/

```
5% 1100
10% 1500
25% 2000
50% 2250
75% 2731
90% 3200
95% 3900
99% 4100
```

Keep in mind that these values are subject to a lot of change as more ranked matchs are played. E.g. the top 1 percentile are probably more towards 5k+ MMR at the current date.

This article on reddit is a very interesting read. http://www.reddit.com/r/DotA2/comments/1y44o4/matchmaking_and_ratings/

Basically someone has created some bots that when added as a friend record their ranked matches and return the data to him. I believe the data is slightly skewed to better players as their average rank is around 3700.